# Невозможно найти файл конфигурации log4j2

Tags: java, apache, log4j2

Почему невозможно найти log4j2 файл конфигурации хотя файл добавлен. Пути файла менял на различные, все равно не находит

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors     to the console.

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию Log4j ищет файл конфигурации с именем log4j2.xml (**не log4j.xml**) в переменной среды `classpath`.

Вы также можете указать полный путь к файлу конфигурации с помощью системного свойства: `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml`.
Это свойство может быть также включено в ресурсный файл `log4j2.component.properties`, расположенный в `classpath`.

Web-приложения могут указать расположение файла конфигурации в контекстных параметрах сервлета: смотрите [Using Log4j 2 in Web Applications](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html#ContextParams).

---

1. [FAQ по Log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#config_location).
2. [Setting the class path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: То, что вы написали, находится на [официальном сайте](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location). Куда именно нужно вписать (в какой файл, в настройки самой IDE) системное свойство `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml`?

Comment: если я прописываю данную настройку в файле конфигурации, то `log4j2` будет в каждом проекте искать расположение файле по прописанному пути либо только в отдельно взятом проекте?

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что надо положить оба файла в корень папки SRС. Единственный вариант, который не попробовал.